# Google Vision распознавание изображений

Tags: веб-служба, распознавание-образов

Подскажите есть ли в открытом доступе примеры запроса к Google Vision?
Или готовые проекты для ознакомления.
Хочется попробовать свои силы.
Уже сделал проект в google, и включил api.
Получил ключ.
Но с чего начать честно говоря теряюсь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начните пока отсюда, дальше уже будет легче: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision